# How to blur an ellipse with ImageDraw

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, imagefilter

I implemented an algorithm that detects faces and I want to blur faces. I'm using PIL for blurring it.

```
image = Image.open(path_img)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.ellipse((top, left, bottom, right), fill = 'white', outline ='white')
```

I got this with my code

[Face to blur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHgOB.png)

I would like to use :

```
blurred_image = cropped_image.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=10 ))
```

But I can't use it because I'm using an ImageDraw and it works only with Image class. How can I blur with an ellipse (circular) the face?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to blur the face, or blur the ellipse now covering the face?

Comment: Both are good for me but I think that blur the ellipse is the best way

Comment: You should consider accepting the answer you prefer by clicking the hollow tick (check-mark) beside the vote counts so it turns green and the author is rewarded with points and future readers know what you consider to be the solution to your question. Up voting useful answers also encourages people to reply to your questions and costs you nothing. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> blur the ellipse is the best way

With Pillow, the best way to do this is to use the blurred ellipse as a blending mask for `composite`.

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter


def make_ellipse_mask(size, x0, y0, x1, y1, blur_radius):
    img = Image.new("L", size, color=0)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    draw.ellipse((x0, y0, x1, y1), fill=255)
    return img.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=blur_radius))


kitten_image = Image.open("kitten.jpg")
overlay_image = Image.new("RGB", kitten_image.size, color="orange")  # This could be a bitmap fill too, but let's just make it orange
mask_image = make_ellipse_mask(kitten_image.size, 150, 70, 350, 250, 5)
masked_image = Image.composite(overlay_image, kitten_image, mask_image)
masked_image.show()
```

Given [this adorable kitten](https://img.purch.com/w/660/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5saXZlc2NpZW5jZS5jb20vaW1hZ2VzL2kvMDAwLzEwNC84MTkvb3JpZ2luYWwvY3V0ZS1raXR0ZW4uanBn) as input, the output is

[image: a censored kitten]

---

*EDIT:* Inspired by Mark Setchell's answer, simply changing the `overlay_image` line to

```py
overlay_image = kitten_image.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=15))
```

gives us this blur variant (with smooth edges for the blur :) )

[image]

---

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you want to composite something over the image to conceal the contents, or blur it. This is more blurry :-)

Starting with Paddington:

[image]

You can go to *"Stealth Mode"* like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter
import numpy as np

# Open image
im = Image.open('paddington.png')

# Make a mask the same size as the image filled with black
mask = Image.new('RGB',im.size)

# Draw a filled white circle onto the black mask
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
draw.ellipse([90,40,300,250],fill=(255,255,255))

# Blur the entire image
blurred = im.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=15))

# Select either the original or the blurred image at each pixel, depending on the mask
res = np.where(np.array(mask)>0,np.array(blurred),np.array(im)) 

# Convert back to PIL Image and save
Image.fromarray(res).save('result.png')
```

[image]

---

Or, as suggested by @AKX, you can remove the Numpy dependency and make the code a bit smaller too yet still get same result:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter
import numpy as np

# Open image
im = Image.open('paddington.png')

# Make a mask the same size as the image filled with black
mask = Image.new('L',im.size)

# Draw a filled white circle onto the black mask
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
draw.ellipse([90,40,300,250],fill=255)

# Blur the entire image
blurred = im.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=15))

# Composite blurred image over sharp one within mask
res = Image.composite(blurred, im, mask)

# Save
res.save('result.png')
```

Comment: Using `Image.composite` would forego the numpy dependency. :)

Comment: @AKX I have never had problems with requiring `Numpy` as it is pretty ubiquitous, but I shall have a try and see if I can do it the way you suggest. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! It solves my problem, you are awesome :)